# how can I connect from db2 for z/os to non DBMS object?

Tags: db2, zos

I would like to connect from db2 for z/os to text file in windows.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think Information Integrator is the solution that you are looking for. There are many different types of federation, and one of them is a file.

For more information take a look at:
http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/classic-federation-server-z/